# "Not enough storage is available to process this command" error in RDP login screen

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

Out of the blue I got the error message in the rdp connection like "Not enough storage is available to process this command" after login to the server and it does not allow me to enter further. The server is windows server 2012. When I got in to the server through kvm console of the softlayer, In the event log there were 3 repeated errors of SChannel with the event code 36888,36874,36887. Although the server hosting became right after half a day,before there was only the main domain was working, sub domains were not accessible. But still RDP error remains. Please help me with this problem..

Thank you,.

**UPDATED**
Before the above mentioned problem the RDP itself was not connecting it was giving the error like "server not found" when i tried to connect. the problem is solved by removing the registry entries i.e TSL1.0, TSL1.1, TSL1.2, SSL3.0 both client and server, It was added before because of poodle vulnerability (mentioned in  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx) . After this only the above mentioned problem remained.

Comment: When I've seen this in the past it's been due to ephemeral port exhaustion. Run `netstat -ano` and see if there are thousands of open ports in the 49152-65535 range. If there are, identify the service/program that has that process ID and restart it.

Comment: It could also implicate a memory leak in software or driver. You can use perfmon to monitor process memory handles to identify the offender.

Comment: Toukakoukan, I only got port id till 1524